# How to get mark the select items

Tags: jquery

can anyone please tell me how can i retrieve data using jquery when i send data using .load() function along with url. In below case how can retrieve the 'data' variable in person.html page..

Is it possible to do this using scripts like jquery, javascript etc?

code:

```
value="name";
```

$("div").load("person.html",{data:value});

another one is

```
ITEMS 1)item1 2)item2 3)item3
```

if i select item1 then it should get selected with Background color and if I click outside somewhere the background color should disappear...

Comment: Please format your question. It is almost absolutely unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments your question is not easy to read.

Load in JQuery works like:

```
$(document).load('someurl', {param: 'somepar'}, function(data){
   // do your stuff here to make things happen
});
```

So to send a predefined var down to person.html you must pass it into the second param within the load function like:

```
{data: "name" }
```

As for the second part of your question...I am not sure sure what items you are on about and what elements they use as such as I cannot give you a reliable answer.

If you can explain more I am sure more people will answer.

Edit:

In your case the load function would look like:

```
var data = "name";
$('div').load('person.htm', {data: data});
```

Hope it helps,